# Django celery db scheduler not working after version upgrade

Tags: celery, django-celery

I'm upgrading celery and django-celery from:

```
celery==2.4.5
django-celery==2.3.3
```

To:

```
celery==3.0.24
django-celery==3.0.23
```

After the pip upgrade i run the migrations and all is well.

I then restarted celery worker and celery beat with the below commands:

```
django-admin.py celery worker --loglevel=DEBUG --config=portal.settings.development -E
django-admin.py celery beat --loglevel=DEBUG --config=portal.settings.development
```

The celery beat initial output shows it knows about the tasks:

```
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://zonza:**@localhost:5672/zonza
    . loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
    . scheduler -> djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[INFO] Wed, 18 Jun 2014 13:31:18 +0000 celery.beat 2184 140177823078144 beat: Starting...
[2014-06-18 13:31:18,332: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: intial read
[2014-06-18 13:31:18,332: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2014-06-18 13:31:18,333: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
[2014-06-18 13:31:18,366: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ModelEntry: SOON_EXPIRY_ALERT SOON_EXPIRY_ALERT(*[], **{}) {4}>
<ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) {4}>
<ModelEntry: REFRESH_DB_CACHE REFRESH_DB_CACHE(*[], **{}) {4}>
```

Now none of my Periodic Tasks run :/ Any ideas?

*edit*: if i change the scheduler setting to the default 'celery.beat.PersistentScheduler' one, the tasks will work. but i think we need to use the djcelery one in this project for a number of reasons

*edit2*: after about 40mins of nothing the tasks now start running properly, this obviously is not ideal, i have no idea why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the changelogs somewhere, but Celery changed from storing dates in local time to storing them in UTC.

The database scheduler is not able to automatically convert to the new format, so you need to reset the last_run_at fields for every periodic task.

Something like:

```
UPDATE djcelery_periodic_task SET last_run_at=NULL
```

Comment: Thanks alot, my hours of pain are over :)